# Dplyr and tidyverse -- correlation between pattern of variables (Same variable VAR1_time1 and VAR1_time2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, correlation, tidyverse

I started this topic on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/208382/dplyr-tidyverse-pipes-correlation-same-variable-across-time-a-b) and asked for crossposting because (comparing to StackOverflow), Code Review has few *dplyr* and *tidyverse* users. Please, feel free to suppress this topic if it's not adequate to this community! But if it is ok, have a look at this dataset. The"a" and "b" are used to make possible differentiate when the same variable was measured. In this case X1a and X1b access the same variable, but "a" was (suppose..) in the last year and "b" was this year.

[image: Original dataframe]

I have a specific goal! I want to correlate "a" and "b" and plot it. X-axis has the variable name (1, 2, 3 etc) and the y-axis has the correlation result. 
[image: Plot]

The fake data I created to help me to clarify this question and the code I've developed are the following:

```
 all_items <- data.frame("1a" = sample(1:5), 
                            "2a" = sample(1:5),
                            "3a" = sample(1:5),
                            "1b" = sample(1:5),
                            "2b" = sample(1:5),
                            "3b" = rep(sample(1:5),10))


    #matrix with correlation
    all_correlation <- cor(all_items, method = "spearman") %>% 
      as.data.frame()

    #filter
    all_correlation <- all_correlation %>% select(-c(ends_with("a"))) #columns

    #create a colum with the now name
    all_correlation <- all_correlation %>% 
      mutate(item = row.names(.)) %>% select(item, everything())

    #supress some rows
    all_correlation <- all_correlation %>%  filter(!grepl("b", item))

    #filter(stringr::str_detect(row.names(.), "b"))
    #get only the diagonal
    all_correlation <- data.frame(item=1:3,Result=diag(as.matrix(all_correlation[, -1])))

    #P Value
    all_correlation_p_value <- Hmisc::rcorr(as.matrix(all_items))$P %>% as.data.frame()

    #filter
    all_correlation_p_value <- all_correlation_p_value %>% select(-c(ends_with("a")))
    all_correlation_p_value <- all_correlation_p_value %>% mutate(item = row.names(.)) %>% select(item, everything())
    all_correlation_p_value <- all_correlation_p_value %>%  filter(!grepl("b", item))
    all_correlation_p_value <- data.frame(item=1:3,P_Valor=diag(as.matrix(all_correlation_p_value[, -1])))

    #General table with the correlation  results
    all_correlation <- right_join(all_correlation,all_correlation_p_value, by = "item")


#Plot
ggplot(all_correlation, aes(x=item, y=Result)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=Result)) +
  geom_line() +
  annotate("text", x = all_correlation$item, 
           y=all_correlation$Result, 
           label = paste("P-value =",round(all_correlation$P_Valor,3)), hjust = -0.1, colour = "red") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(1,3,1))
```

Thank you.

Comment: as far as I see, the question has an accepted answer on the link which you provided?

Comment: @Tjebo, yes! Thanks. I will update

Answer (score 0):

I've got an answer on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/208382/dplyr-tidyverse-pipes-correlation-same-variable-across-time-a-b) and I put it on here to everyone can access. Credits to [flodel](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/16479/flodel)

Here are two possible rewrites. For the first one, notice how `Hmisc::rcorr` already computes `correlations ($r`) and `p-values ($P)` matrices so you can base all your work from it, provided you extract the rights rows (a_vars) and columns (b_vars) and only keep the diagonal values:

```
correlations <- rcorr(as.matrix(all_items), type = "spearman")
a_vars <- ends_with("a", vars = names(all_items))
b_vars <- ends_with("b", vars = names(all_items))
all_correlation <- data.frame(
  item    = seq_along(a_vars),
  Result  = diag(correlations$r[a_vars, b_vars]),
  P_Valor = diag(correlations$P[a_vars, b_vars])
)
```

What I don't like too much about this approach is that it only uses 3 of the 36 correlations that were computed by rcorr. In this second approach, I start by splitting the data into two tables (one for a and one for b) so as to compute only 3 correlations via Map. I also switched from rcorr to the base cor.test which has (IMO) a more intuitive behavior: when given two vectors as input, it computes one correlation, not four.

```
a <- all_items %>% select(ends_with("a"))
b <- all_items %>% select(ends_with("b"))
cor_test <- Map(cor.test, a, b)
all_correlation <- data.frame(
  item    = seq_along(a),
  Result  = sapply(cor_test, `[[`, "estimate"),
  P_Valor = sapply(cor_test, `[[`, "p.value")
)
```